Properly Selecting the CFR-LM Font
I'm trying to reproduce a problem I've been having with my project in which, when I select the cfr-lm package/font, I get warnings saying that it isn't defined and that TeX is going to default to lmodern.
LaTeX Font: Font shape `TU/clm/m/n' undefined
(Font)  using `TU/lmr/m/n' instead.

This is the closest I've been able to reproduce things minimally:
\documentclass[12pt]{book}

% \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

% \usepackage[default]{fontsetup}
% \newfontfamily\ncm{NewCM10-Regular.otf}
% \setmainfont{NewCM10-Regular.otf}

\usepackage[rm={proportional,lining},sf={proportional,lining},tt={tabular,lining,monowidth}]{cfr-lm}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Adobe Garamond Pro} % Could be any font, this is just a placeholder

\begin{document}
  % \fontfamily{ncm}\selectfont
  % \ncm
  
  abc123456789

  \fontfamily{clm}\selectfont

  \textsb{abc123456789}

  \textbf{abc123456789}
\end{document}

I've tried so many variations on trying to select this font, I really don't have any idea of why, in the example above, if you choose NewCM + CFR-LM, there's no warning, but there's a warning if I choose Adobe Garamond Pro + CFR-LM.
I'm trying to use cfr-lm with TikZ in order to draw numbers in diagrams, because it offers more variants, and there are variants with numbers on the same baseline. The code I use with TikZ looks like this:
\draw (\xCoordShifted, \yCoordShifted) 
  node[
    color     = -\StoneColor{#2},
    font      = \fontfamily{clm}\fontsize{\fontSize}{9pt}\selectfont,
  ] {\textbf{#3}};


Edit
Following this other answer, and @cfr's comments, I've also tried this, which still gives me a warning — I'm basically setting main font twice, how do I set them as \newfontfamily? —:
\documentclass[10pt, varwidth, preview]{standalone}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\setmainfont[
  Scale = 1.0,
  Ligatures = {Common, Discretionary, TeX},
  FontFace={sb}{n}{Font = {lmromandemi10-regular}, Extension = .otf },
  FontFace={sb}{it}{Font = {lmromandemi10-oblique}, Extension = .otf }
]{Latin Modern Roman}

\defaultfontfeatures{ Scale=MatchLowercase, Ligatures=TeX }

% The commands to select semibold weight:
\DeclareRobustCommand\sbseries{\fontseries{sb}\selectfont}
\DeclareTextFontCommand{\textsb}{\sbseries}

\setmainfont{Adobe Garamond Pro} % Could be any font, this is just a placeholder

\begin{document}
    \Huge
    Not bold enough
    
    \fontfamily{lmr}\selectfont

    {\bfseries Too} \textbf{bold}

    {\sbseries Just} \textsb{right}
\end{document}

This is the warning I'm getting:
LaTeX Font: Font shape `TU/lmr/sb/n' undefined
(Font)  using `TU/lmr/b/n' instead.


you can access everything cfr-lm provides using fontspec and the default latin modern. you do not need cfr-lm on unicode engines.

your second \setmainfont just overwrites the first. you would have exactly the same issue if you loaded cfr-lm and then redefined the default serif family with pdfTeX. you have to set up some distinct macro to switch to lmr if you want something else as your main font. note that this is typographically questionable at best. you would be better advised to choose a single serif (excepting decorative uses, perhaps). generally, most diagrams look better in sans anyway, but that's not especially congenial to a garamond.

The warning is a direct result of the commands you show, you select a semi bold Latin modern that doesn't exist and it warns,  and selects bold instead, what output did you expect?

The garamond is unrelated to the question you could remove it from your example

Do not use cfr-lm with a Unicode engine.
cfr-lm provides extended support for Latin Modern on 8bit engines i.e. pdfTeX or TeX. There is no cfr-lm font. The package doesn't provide fonts in the ordinary sense at all. It provides virtual fonts, which are just fancy wrappers around other real fonts. cfr-lm was written because lmodern provided access to only a fraction of the functionality available to users of Unicode engines, even though the type1 fonts were as complete as their opentype cousins.
If you are using a Unicode engine such as LuaTeX or XeTeX, you can access the same features using regular fontspec settings.
I cannot test your example as-is because I do not have the proprietary font Adobe Garamond Pro. So I commented that out, but you should be able to uncomment it because I did not set Latin Modern up as the main font. (It is the main font by default, but I provide an alternative way to access it below.)
I do not have extensive experience with Unicode fonts, so I do not know if this answer will remain, but you need to use fontspec to set things up. I also provide a simplified way to access semi-bold. Note that this is not as careful as the definition used by cfr-lm (from nfssext-cfr), but I think it should be enough to deal with Latin Modern Roman's limited semi-bold offering.

\clmuni -> serif, proportional, lining
\clmssuni -> sans, proportional, lining
\clmttuni -> mono, tabular, lining

\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\usepackage{fontspec}
% \setmainfont{Adobe Garamond Pro}
\newfontfamily\clmuni{Latin Modern Roman}
[%
  Numbers={Lining,Proportional},%
  FontFace={sb}{n}{Font=lmromandemi10-regular.otf},%
  FontFace={sb}{sl}{Font=lmromandemi10-oblique.otf},%
]
\newfontfamily\clmssuni{Latin Modern Sans}[Numbers={Lining,Proportional}]
\newfontfamily\clmttuni{Latin Modern Mono}[Numbers={Lining}]

\makeatletter
\DeclareRobustCommand{\sbweight}{%
  \not@math@alphabet\sbweight\relax
  \fontseries{sb}\selectfont
}
\makeatother
\DeclareTextFontCommand{\textsb}{\sbweight}
\begin{document}
% should be in AGP if you uncomment the line above
% but I can't test this
abc123456789

\clmuni

abc1234567890

\textsb{abc123456789}

\textbf{abc123456789}
\end{document}

Note that the semi-bold looks bolder to me than the bog-standard bold, though it isn't extended.

Cool, but I still get warnings if I only use fontspec without cfr-lm. And how would I then specify the rm, sf, etc. options with only fontspec?

You mean I specify it with \fontfamily{lmr}? How do I access semibold?

Maybe like in this other answer? It doesn't seem to work exactly as expected, I still get a warning. I'll add an edit to my answer.

@psygo you should hardly ever need to use \fontfamily at the document level. usually, you set things up so you don't need to except, possibly, for small stretches where you want something specialist. see edit.

@psygo yes, like that, but TeX ligatures are default now. I more-or-less copied the fontspec from an example in the manual (but without making the text red!). nfssext-cfr (and so cfr-lm) tries to merge the weight, which the code above doesn't. however, the kernel now tries to do this at least sometimes and it makes no difference for latin modern anyway, as there really isn't anything to merge with.

You can download the AGP from my project's asset folder, if you would like. But you can replace that command with any font, it was just a placeholder.

In your example, sans and mono give me this warning: Package fontspec: OpenType feature 'Numbers=Monospaced' (tnum) not (fontspec) available for font 'LatinModernMono' with script (fontspec) 'CustomDefault' and language 'Default'.

@psygo corrected, thanks. it's a monospaced font, so tabular isn't an extra option.
